# TableView inside CollectionView is setting frame after scrolling?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am using `UITableView` inside `UICollectionViewCell`. What I am trying to show is dynamic height of `tableView` depending upon cells in `UITableView`.But its frame is setting after scrolling `UICollectionView`.Here is the code what i tried.

```
#Pragma mark-CollectionView Methods 
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [_collectionViewLabelArray count];
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UICollectionViewCell *myCell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UITableView *tableView=(UITableView*)[myCell viewWithTag:11];
tableView.delegate=self;
tableView.dataSource=self;
[tableView reloadData];
tableView.frame=CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width,tableView.contentSize.height);
    return myCell;
}
 -(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


return CGSizeMake(950, [_tableViewDataArray count]*44);
}
#pragma mark-TableView Methods
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [_tableViewDataArray count];
 }
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *myCell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];


myCell.textLabel.text=[_tableViewDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return myCell;

 }
```

Comment: what is the need to set height of tableView?

Comment: I am trying to set dyanamic height. Further the data will pulled from JSON.SO i have to show dyanamic height of `tableView` (As in my requirement i don't need to scroll `tableView`)

Answer (score 0):

Reload your tableView after setting tableView frame.

```
tableView.frame=CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width,tableView.contentSize.height);
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: No, Its not showing any effect.Showing same behavior as previous one.

Comment: once change name of your tableView object instead of tableView.